# Не получается использовать copy_file

Tags: c++, linux, файлы, файловая-система

Хотелось бы понять, почему данный код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
string pathfrm, pathto;
for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
    pathfrm=argv[1];
    pathto=argv[2];
    copy_file(pathfrm, pathto);
}
return 0;
}
```

дает ошибку еще на этапе интерпретации в редакторе

> `ошибка: use of undeclared identifier 'copy_file'`

Тогда как в [примере](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file) все вроде описано и разжевано и как бы программа должна работать.

Сделал все правильно как советовали. Ошибки в интерпретаторе пропали. Код красным не посвечивается, но программа не собирается так как ругается на ссылки `experimental::flesystem`.

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string pathfrm, pathto;
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
        pathfrm=argv[1];
        pathto=argv[2];
        std::experimental::filesystem::copy_file(pathfrm, pathto);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вот ошибки:

> :-1: ошибка: main.o: in function
> `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::copy_file(std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path const&, std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path const&)':    /usr/include/c++/10/experimental/bits/fs_ops.h:74: ошибка: undefined reference to` std::experimental::filesystem::v1::copy_file(std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path
> const&, std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path const&,
> std::experimental::filesystem::v1::copy_options)'   :-1: ошибка:
> main.o: in function
> `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::path<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':   :-1: ошибка: main.o: in function` std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::path<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator >,
> std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)':   :-1:
> ошибка: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

И программа, с таким количеством проблем, не работает.
Не могу понять, что мне сделать. Я подозреваю, что компилятор себя неправильно ведет. Но не понимаю как все завести.

UPD: Нашел почему не работает filsystem - нужно было добавить флаг в .pro файл `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17` и пересобрать все.
Подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610996/cant-use-c17-features-using-g-7-2-in-qtcreator/49192230#49192230)
Но в моем случае все можно было сделать еще проще:
В терминале

```
c++ -std=c++17 /путь/к/файлу/main.cpp/моей/программы
```

UPD: В файле main.cpp добавил `break;` после операции копирования ибо если этого не сделать то по итогу программа будет делать копирование а дальше: "Аварийный останов. Стек памяти сброшен на диск".
Итоговый код программы такой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string pathfrm, pathto;
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
        pathfrm=argv[1];
        pathto=argv[2];
        std::filesystem::copy_file(pathfrm, pathto);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В примере есть такая строчка: `namespace fs = std::filesystem;` и `fs::copy_file("sandbox/abc", "sandbox/def");`

Comment: @timur не помогает добавление пространства имен. Я это в первую очередь попробовал. Сорян что не написал сразу.

Comment: там `::` вместо `/` должно быть...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48729328/6944845

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак. Все по полочкам. Если кто-то столкнется с таким.
Я использую qtcreator, qtcreator для компиляции консольных приложений без qt использует gcc системы(у меня это  Fedora). У меня gcc версии 10.1.1.
В первую очередь необходимо добавить флаг в файл .pro в дереве файлов проекта. Содержимое файла не удалять, а лишь в строке

```
CONFIG += console c++1x //у меня вместо x было 11
```

`x` изменить на нужный вам стандарт c++. У меня эта строка стала выглядеть так

```
CONFIG += console c++17
```

И добавить в этот файл строку

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1x
```

Где вместо `x` нужная вам.
У меня файл стал выглядеть вот так

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
```

Далее - пересобираем проект.
Если вам, как и мне, удобно работать в терминале linux, то можно вот так скомпилировать код(без использования qtcreator)
В терминале вводим:

```
cd
```

далее

```
c++ -std=c++17 /путь/к/файлу/main.cpp/в/котором/ваш/код //вместо 17 нужный вам стандарт
```

В папке `/home/<name>` будет создан файл `a.out`.
Если во время ввода команды компиляции вы будете в другой директории(например `/home/<name>/Изоражения`), то файл `a.out` будет создан в папке `Изображения`.
Файл `a.out` можно переименовать и запускать

```
./<name_of_a.out_file>
```

Либо переместить переименованный `a.out` файл в папку `/bin` с правами суперпользователя и запускать без `./`
Либо просто запускать без переименования и без переноса:

```
./a.out <argument> <arument>
```

Answer (score 5):

Укажите пространство имен:

```
filesystem::copy_file(paths, path1);
```

Comment: это не помогло.  И   `std::filesystem::copy_file(paths, path1);`  тоже не помогло. В этих вариантах начинает ругаться на `filesystem`.

Comment: @umd https://godbolt.org/z/jxadrY

Comment: Могу только показать, что VC++ это с исправленными именами компилирует: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/14a4oT Возможно, ваш компилятор не поддерживает последние нововведения?...

Comment: @Harry понял вас. Погожу, возможно линуксоиды знаю что здесь за дичь

Comment: Все, увидел ошибку. У меня было experimental`/`filesystem а должно быть experimental`::`filesystem

Comment: @Harry я правильно понимаю, что copy_file осталась в experimental?

Comment: Думаю, что нет. Скорее всего, ваш компилятор несколько отстал от жизни. Чем вы пользуетесь?

Comment: @Harry gcc v 10.1.1+ qmake. Но сейчас собираю все без qt(Приложения без Qt)

Comment: @umd На 10-ом гцц `experimental` не нужен ни там ни там. Если этот ответ у вас не работает, то скорее всего забыли флажок `-std=c++17`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а в qtcreator его куда? я его ставил только в netbeans

Comment: @umd Не знаю, не пользовался им...

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <experimental/filesystem>

//...

std::experimental::filesystem::copy_file(pathfrm, pathto);
```

Comment: ну и это пробовал. Все варианты с пространством имен пробовал, ничего не завелось.